# Metadata file 'E:\MyProject\Core-Angular\Core-Angular.Common\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Core-Angular.Common.dll' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

i using class library in my project . but when i Rebuild the project it show me this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       E:\MyProject\Core-Angular\Core-Angular.DomainClass\error CS0006: Metadata file 'E:\MyProject\Core-Angular\Core-Angular.Common\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Core-Angular.Common.dll' could not be found  CoreAngular.DomainClass C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

i add class library with `Add Refrence` and add that in `Project.json` but also it show me error .

Refrence :

[image: Refrence]

whats the problem ?

i do this ways :

A : i right click on my project but i cant find `Configuration` .

B :

```
* Clean every project individually (Right click the project -> Clean).
* Rebuild every project individually (Right click the project -> Rebuild).
* Rebuild the startup project (Right click the project -> Rebuild).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using an old version of the related tool-sets. Theses days, you have only 2 major choices for developing .NET Core apps:

- VS 2017
- VSCode

VS 2015 won't be supported anymore and you can't use newer SDK's with that. It's over and it's officially announced that VS 2015 won't be updated for .NET Core anymore.